# IIS User Accessing Network Share Folder In Work Group Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

We have 2 servers. 10.30.1.1 is the application server and 10.30.1.2 is the storage server. Now, we need to read and write files from application server to storage server folder. We are simply using `File.Writexxx` and `File.Readxxx` methods but getting permission errors (`DirectoryNotFoundException`). Our app is deployed in IIS.

As per App Pool Identity we can use `<domainname>\<machinename>$,`
` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#accessing-the-network but our servers are on workgroup not on domain.

Comment: Based on your description, I can't clearly know what permission error you are encountering. Please post more details about the error.

Comment: DirectoryNotFoundException in short

Comment: You need to set up both servers to allow file sharing and also check firewall rules to allow traffic between the two servers.

Comment: Which account as AppPoolIdentity is local account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a user logon + password on the 1.2 - not a domain logon, but a simple user logon on/for that computer.

Then create a user on 1.1 - same name + password.

Then in app pool, specify that user.

[image]

The result is that your code behind should be able to freely use + update files on 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give IIS App Pool Identity permission to access the shared folder. Right click on the shared folder and select Properties > select the Security tab > click the Edit button > click the Add button > enter a name for the IIS App Pool Identity > click the Check Names button to verify Name > Click the OK to add the user to the user or group list > Grant the user read/write permissions.
[image]